# how can I get better url's from drupal views taxonomy filtered pages

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have a Drupal view with a page display that's using dynamic filtering based on taxonomy terms. Pretty straight forward but I'd like to be able to change the url's that are generated from [page path]/[term name] to something more user friendly. I thought I could do this by just substituting the url alias of the taxonomy terms in place of the term name but apparently I can't. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to create links for every taxonomy, and use module that will redirect to your new alias (Path redirect module).
Other way is to turn off automatic links for taxonomy (many modules do that), and create your own view with any url. If you use filters in views, you can define param name, so your links can look better.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying regarding creating my own view with the url. Could you elaborate?

To recap: I made about 50 pages by using dynamic filtering of my view page display with a taxonomy category. But the original taxonomy terms that were created are not very user friendly and I'd like to find a way to change them.

Thank you.